# Checking if only 1 single value in the request that received

Tags: json, go, decode

There is something strange which I don't understand.
In the line that is:

```
err = dec.Decode(&struct{}{})
```

I have this function:

```
func (app *Config) readJSON(w http.ResponseWriter,r http.Request,data any) error {
    maxBytes := 1048576
    r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w,r.Body,int64(maxBytes))
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err := dec.Decode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = dec.Decode(&struct{}{})
    if err != io.EOF {
        return errors.New("Body must have only a single JSON body")
    }

    return nil
}
```

What is the logic behind the line that only single json body:
in:
Why do I need to pass ref to double curly brackets in the Decode func?

```
dec.Decode(&struct{}{})
```

also why only '=" is used and not ":=" ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly - the code simply checks if the JSON is valid.
The dec.Decode() does decode the whole json to a variable that you pass to it. But in your case the variable is declared and initialized right in the method, and never used after that, which means that it is not used. So the method is only called to see if it will throw an error. 

Concerning the "=" instead of ":=",  we don't need the ":" because "err" variable was already declared before few lines above and it is only reused here.

Comment: About the decode i dont see it any where in the documentions that say that empty struct will prevent form it to decode more then 1 json

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.20.2#Decoder.Decode) for `(*Decoder).Decode`

> ```
> func (dec *Decoder) Decode(v any) error
> ```
>
> Decode reads the next JSON-encoded value from its input and stores it in the value pointed to by v.

That means it is valid to decode the following content (the first json object is read):

```json
{
  "a":1
}
{
  "b":2
}
```

`readJSON` wants to prevent such kind of input, so it calls `err = dec.Decode(&struct{}{})` to check if the decoder has reached the end of the input.

`struct{}` defines a type, `struct{}{}` creates a new instance of that type, and `&struct{}{}` references that new instance. It is equivalent to

```golang
type empty struct{}
e := empty{}
err = dec.Decode(&e)
```

In fact, I think it's better to use [`(*Decoder).More`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.20.2#Decoder.More) here.

> also why only '=" is used and not ":=" ?

`:=` is used in a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). The variable `err` has been declared before. Here we only want to assign a new value to it and don't want to declare it again, so `=` is used.

Comment: tnx, the thing i dont understand and its not in the documention is how come i need to know that passing empty struct will prevent me decoder to decode more then one json object . i dont see it explaned any where ...

Comment: It does not prevent it from decoding more that one json object. Instead, It is used to check whether the decoder has reached the end of the input. If it's reached the end of the input (means there is only one object), the second call of `decode` returns `io.EOF`.

Comment: The empty struct here only means that it does not care about what is left behind the first object. Its purpose is to make the statement syntactically correct. The key is to get the `err`. If there is anything left, the `err` won't be `io.EOF`.

Comment: where can i read about this , can't find it anyware @Zeke Lu

Comment: If you mean `io.EOF`, you can find it here: https://pkg.go.dev/io@go1.20.2#pkg-variables.

Comment: no i mean this : 
dec.Decode(&struct{}{})

Comment: This is only a practice usage. I'm not aware of any documentation about it.

Comment: how did you learn about it ? maybe tutorial that explans or something

Comment: From the discussion of github issues: https://github.com/golang/go/issues